# PHP MySQL - Display saved forms submitted by a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm an up an coming developer trying to develop an online ordering system. Basically users will login to a system, create a form, save a form and display previously saved forms.

I can create a login system, i can create a form, and i know how to save/edit the forms but my problem is how do i only show forms submitted by specific users. If Joe logs into the system, i only want Joe to be able to see his saved forms.

Should i have a form database per user? Should i just have a login database and one single form database for all users?

Comment: When you save form in database store id of user who is submitted and After login store session with id of user so fetch the data based on that user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work to have two tables inside your database:

- `users` for storing user info. It should have things like a unique ID column, the user's name, email...
- `forms` for saved forms. It should have a `user_id` column so you know for any given form what user saved it. This stores the the fields in the form.